# Retrieving recent songs from the MediaStore

Tags: java, android, mediastore

After some research, I still haven't quite figured out how I would query for songs within the last 7 days. Currently, this is how I have tried to retrieve the songs, but it always seems to return empty.

```
public void displayRecentSongs() {

    //retrieve song info
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED + ">" + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - 7);
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, where, null, null);

    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int pathColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            String thisPath = musicCursor.getString(pathColumn);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, null, thisPath));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    musicCursor.close();

}
```

Note: I have tested it to double check if it would query for songs I have downloaded within the last week, but to no avail.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - 7` would be the number of seconds since the Unix epoch, minus seven seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - 7` is seven seconds before now, expressed in seconds since the Unix epoch.

`System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - 7*60*60*24` would be seven days before now, expressed in seconds since the Unix epoch. You should be able to get that `7*60*60*24` calculation from `TimeUnit` (`TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(7, TimeUnit.DAYS)`?), but I haven't tried that, and I'm slightly confused by [the `TimeUnit` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html).